# Xamarin.Android Creating Xamarin.ios.dll files

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, monodevelop

Our app appears to be creating Xamarin.ios.dll files within the debug folders on the build. we then get the following error on certain events

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065' or one of its dependencies.

We believe this is coming from one of the packages added to the project. is there an easy way to discover which package it is?

**Assembly Folder:**

[image]

After removing Xamarin.forms and adding the the latest version im still not given the option add the Xamarin.forms to the shared references.

**References which can be added:**

[image]

The app will only build if Xamarin.iOS is with the Assembly folder as shown in the previous image

we get this Error if we do not add the Xamerin.iOS.dll to the shared assembly folder:

[image]

Reported as an issue in VS

Comment: Check if by mistake you have cross dependencies

Comment: @FreakyAli under our dependencies/assemblies folder we only have a Xamarin.ios should there the an android variant of this? its only thing that appears to be wrong with the dependencies. Im still relatively new to Xamarin

I will add a reference image to the question above

Comment: Can't you just remove it manually? The thing is your Android project should have Mono.Android and your ios should have Xamarin.iOS

Comment: yeah iOS project has the Xamarin.iOS and Android project contains its mono.android. So I don't need the Xamarin.iOS within the shared Assembly?

Comment: removing the shared assembly causes errors with our _using userNotifications_ and _using Foundation_. If you search for reference usages within VS it returns 0

Comment: You don't need Mono.Android or Xamarin.iOS in shared, you just need Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Yes because UserNotifications is a part of IOS for Xamarin Forms check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

Comment: doesnt give us an option to have Xamarin forms within the shared assembly folder but we are able to add the mono.android to the shared folder but still results in the same issue

Comment: Please use text only for code and error messages, screenshots are only useful for showing what you're seeing on the screen when it visuals are really necessary to understand the context. Code and error messages are easier to read and process as text.

Comment: @ewerspej the screenshot was used cause VS Mac wouldn't allow me to copy the text.

Answer (score -1):

"Xamarin.iOS" is contained in "Xamarin.Forms", so try to uninstall the "Xamarin.Forms" Nuget Package and install the latest version.

Then delete the "bin" and "obj" folder under project path, and clean&rebuild the project.

Comment: after doing still getting the same issues. the app will only build with the Xamarin.iOS.dll added to the shared assemblies. ive added a second reference image to the question showing all the available references that can be added

Comment: That is odd. Actually, Xamarin.Android don't need the Xamarin.iOS.dll file. There might be something wrong with your project.

Comment: the stranger bit is that this only became an issue after updating frameworks about a year ago, but if you revert back the frameworks it still then has the same issues but an older machine we have that never got updated works fine.

Comment: This might be something wrong with the new framework. The project is not compatible with the new version.

Comment: that's why we tried to revert but we still get the same issues after going back. even on a fresh install from a new machine. just a weird bug we can't seem to overcome

Comment: This is a bug on the visual studio. You can report the problem on the website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022